# Using parent/child lists as lookup column on a document library

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, site-column, content-type

I am using SharePoint Foundation and have created a parent and child list which both have a Title field. The child list has an additional lookup column to the parent list.

This enables me to enter data in the child list, and link it to the parent values.

I have a Document Library, and I'd like the user to first pick a parent value, then a valid child value when creating a new document.

Any pointers on how this can be achived? I've tried adding the Child list as a column on the doclib, but I can't choose to display the projected parent field. Or can it be achieved via a content type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mikael - The functionality you are looking for is often referred to as "cascading dropdowns" in case you need to do a search on it in the future.

There is a CodePlex project dedicated to pulling this off using JavaScript.  Read about it here: http://www.sharepointboris.net/js/spcd/

Also, a similar question was asked on the MSDN forums and got other possible solutions.  Since you are using SharePoint 2010 Foundation, I believe the link I mentioned above is the best.  For your reference, however, here is the MSDN thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/260f75a3-8a15-4cdc-9c1b-a7a9fb9985e9

Comment: Seems like something I can use. As an intermediate solution I created a Formula columns which concatenates the two levels. It works for now as I don't have that many combinations.